# presence vs. honour

Tags: formal-language

usually one writes: requests with pleasure the company of (and then includes the name of the person)

Is it possible to write: requests with honour the company of (and then the name of the person)

Is it grammatically correct in a formal situation (invitation) to use the word honour instead of pleasure?

Comment: I think you mean "request **the pleasure of** the company of", instead of "with pleasure"? Also, your title uses "presence", not "pleasure".

Comment: How is this "presence vs honour"? It looks like you're asking the difference between "pleasure" and "honour"?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have it backwards.

We ask a possible guest to *honour us with their presence*. They honour **us**, we do not modestly honour them simply because we asked them to attend.

A **formal** invitation could be worded: [Invitation wording](https://www.invitationconsultants.com/sw-main.aspx) There are less formal samples at the link.

The pleasure of your company is requested for (the reason/at/date/time/by Mr. R).

The honour of your company is requested for  (the reason/at/date/time/by Mr. R).